# Calculating curl$\vec Q(r,t) = \vec Ae^{i \vec k \vec r - it}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, vectors

I want to find a way how to calculate the curl $\nabla$ of some vector, which depends on $r$ and the expression of this vector contains an imaginary number. Are there any special rules for this?

I have some simple vector $\vec Q(r,t) = \vec Ae^{i \vec k \vec r - it}$, where $t$ is time, $\vec k$ and $\vec A$ are some constant vectors, and $\vec r = (x,y,z)$. $\nabla = (\frac {\partial}{\partial x},\frac {\partial}{\partial y},\frac {\partial}{\partial z})$. $\vec Q(r)$ is a vector so it also has $x,y,z$ components: $\vec Q(r) = (Q_x, Q_y, Q_z)$. I know this $\nabla \times \vec Q(\vec r)$ equals to another vector and generally it would look something like this $(\frac {\partial Q_y}{\partial z} - \frac {\partial Q_z}{\partial y} ,\frac {\partial Q_z}{\partial x} - \frac {\partial Q_x}{\partial z},\frac {\partial Q_x}{\partial y} - \frac {\partial Q_y}{\partial x})$. And we can write $\vec Q(r,t) = \vec Ae^{i \vec k \vec (x,y,z) - it}$.

I don't know how to derivate $\vec Q(r)$ correctly and what to do with the imaginary numbers.

**EDIT**

Well if I have $\nabla \times  \vec r$ that I can write it as $(\frac {\partial y}{\partial z} - \frac {\partial z}{\partial y} ,\frac {\partial z}{\partial x} - \frac {\partial x}{\partial z},\frac {\partial x}{\partial y} - \frac {\partial y}{\partial x})$, but how would in my case look like $\vec Q_x, \vec Q_y, \vec Q_z$?

My opinion is that if $\vec Q(x,t) = \vec Ae^{i \vec k \vec (x,0,0) - it}$ etc., then $\nabla \times \vec Q(\vec r) = 0$?

Comment: Use curl in spherical coordinates: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates

Comment: There's nothing special about the imaginary exponent. Just proceed as you said. I'd suggest to avoid using spherical coordinates. That only becomes handy when you can select one (or both) constant vectors $\vec A$ or $\vec k$ in a significative direction, e.g.: the $z$ axis

Comment: Should this be $<\vec k, \vec r> $? It makes no sense to simply multiply vectors, so I'm assuming you mean dot product

Comment: Also, @rrogerr is correct on this, it makes no difference to have an $i$, you just treat it like any other constant when differentiating (you will get a complex vector as an answer). If you seek only the part, then expand first using Euler's identity, then take the curl and take the real part.

Comment: Ok, thank you, maybe I was confused with one example where we were using an identity for complex numbers and I didn't understand it properly.

Comment: But how would $\vec Q_x$ look like for example, I have written something in the question, but I actually don't know.